# Angular 6 setting headers on httpClient question

Tags: angular, observable

Could someone explain how it is possible that the following code works? I would have thought `httpOptions` used in `getClientName` would be set to `null` as it is an `async` call but seems like it's not the case. Is it just timing that makes it work? Apologies if this is a basic misunderstanding. 
Thanks

```
private httpOptions(): {
  headers: HttpHeaders
} {
  var result: {
    headers: HttpHeaders
  } = null;

  this.authService.getAccessToken().subscribe(res => {
    result = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + res
      })
    };
    console.log('UserService ' + res);
  });

  return result;
}

public getClientName(): Observable < string > {
  return this.http.get < ClientResult > (
    "/management/client/" + this.clientId,
    this.httpOptions()
  ).pipe(
    map(res => {
      return res.name
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: My guess would be, `result` is an `Object` that is passed by `ref` and not pass by `value`. That's why it works. And of course there would be just timing. As initially, `result` was `null`.

Comment: What does `authService.getAccessToken` look like?

Comment: This can only work, when the Observable gives back a value immediately (i.e. the callback is called synchronously, before the subscribe returns).

Comment: I agree with @Henry, it must be because you are making a request to localhost.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments? Can an observable call back synchronously? Perhaps though result could get set in the subscribe callback before it is returned in the calling function. getAccessToken can either return local data or do another http call. If it's local data it uses the of operator to convert to an observable.   Also it not going to localhost.

Comment: Yep, if `getAccessToken` is getting data locally, that will be why. Observables can behave synchronously (like using `of` for example)